# Numpy Array and axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A` which has the shape `(2, n)` and second array `B` with the shape `(n, 2)` and I want to create an array `C` with the shape `(n, 2, 2)` by multiplying `axis=0` of the first array `A` and `axis=1` of the second array `B` to receive 10 "arrays" of the shape `(2, 2)` which are stored in the array `C`

I dont know how to do this... hope someone can help, thanks in advance!

Here some test data with n=10:

```
A = [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2]), array([2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 8, 5, 2, 1])]
B = [array([1, 2]), array([3, 2]), array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([6, 1]), array([4, 5]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 2])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) to change the array shapes to line up, then insert additional axes as necessary:

```
C = np.moveaxis(A, 1, 0)[..., None] * B[:, None, ...]
```

Another way would be to apply it after the multiplication, but that would run the risk of creating a non-contiguous memory layout, and is therefore generally less desirable:

```
C = np.moveaxis(A[..., None] * B[None, ...], 1, 0)
```

Similar results can be achieved with [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy.swapaxes).